# Connection failed: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server - AJAX and AWS

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, amazon-web-services

I am trying to insert some data from the client browser to a MySQL database on AWS server.

The code worked on godaddy so it looks like a permissions/security issue.

```
$servername = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
$username = "user";
$password = "mypass";
$dbname = "dbName";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ('email')
VALUES ('" . $email . "')";

echo $sql;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

I am getting the error saying "Connection failed: Host x.x.x.x  is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server "

How do I allow connections to this from a client browser?

I have already commented out the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: You could add 0.0.0.0

Comment: @David I have granted my user all permissions. Now i get the error 'Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)'. I should probably add that the php script is sitting on the same EC2 instance as the MYSQL instance in a LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

If Mysql is a remote host, than use private IP address of source system to be allowed as AWS would use private IP address to communicate by default.